# Select distinct customers and sum orders from XML file using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-xml, sum, distinct

So far, I have a simple LINQ query using an XML file to build a dictionary or customerid and order:

> var Limit = from c in xml.Descendants("Customer")
>                                 select new
>                                 {
>                                     customerID = c.Descendants("customerid").First().Value,
>                                     order = c.Descendants("order").First().Value,
>
> ```
>                           };
> ```

I need distinct customer IDs coming back and the total of the 'order's for each customerID. For example I have:

CustomerID = 123     Order = 200

CustomerID = 123     Order = 100

CustomerID = 123     Order = 50

CustomerID = 456 Order = 100

CustomerID = 456 Order = 100

and I need:

Customer ID = 123   OrderTotal = 350

CustomerID = 456   OrderTotal = 200

I know there are plenty of similar questions out there but I'm pretty new to LINQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to write code without seeing the exact XML input structure but try along the following lines:

```
var query = from cust in xml.Descendants("Customer")
            group cust by (int)cust.Element("customerid") into g
            select new {
              customerID = g.Key,
              total = g.Elements("order").Sum(el => (decimal)el)
            }
```

[edit]
With the sample mentioned in your comment you want

```
var query = from cust in xml.Descendants("Customer")
            group cust by (int)cust.Element("customerid") into g
            select new {
              customerID = g.Key,
              total = g.Elements("ordertotal").Sum(el => (decimal)el)
            }
```

Comment: My XML is as follows                                          <Customer>
  <customerid>123</customerid> 
  <ordertotal>100</ordertotal> 
    </Customer>
<Customer>
  <customerid>123</customerid> 
  <ordertotal>300</ordertotal> 
    </Customer><Customer>
  <customerid>456</customerid> 
  <ordertotal>100</ordertotal> 
    </Customer>